Formalizing a Theory in a Universe and Model vs Universe question
A basic question about a terminology on foundation of set theory: What does it mean to "formalize a formal theory (ie a collection of syntactically welldefined sentences with resp. to some underlying formal language; see wiki) in certain universe"?
Idea/ guess: Does it just mean to endow free variables of formulas of the theory with a "domain", ie class of all sets etc, essentially where these can be partially evaluated? Is it correct?
Eg, if $\Psi(x)$ is some formula with free variable $x$, then does formalizing the theory in a universe mean that the universe $U$ contains set or sets where $\Psi(x)$ can be evaluated? Ie informally to give free variable $x$ a domain?
If yes, isn't this the same as to choose a model of the considered theory and so making the formula a predicate of this model?
Is it correct meaning of the quoted statement? Moreover, what are differences & similarities between a universe in set theoretic sense and a model in model theor sence? Can a universe be considered to be synonymously to a model $M$ (if we allow the underlying "bare" domains $\vert M \vert$ to classes than just sets; ie "class models") in we "forget" models signatures? So is it essentially the same?
Motivation: discussion here with Asaf Karaglia arosing initially on precising the meaning of term "meta theoretic integers".

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

It seems to me that one simply uses the term "universe" when dealing with models in a set-theoretic context, such as ZF, etc.  If one is dealing for example with models of Peano Arithmetic, it would be inappropriate to use the term "universe".  Here universe could refer to a superstructure, cumulative hierarchy, etc.  So it seems to me that the answer to your question is simpler than you may have expected.  I would be glad to be proven wrong.
